# Redshift JSON Performance

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Redshift provides a set of JSON functions that allows performing JSON operations but did anyone have tested the performance of JSON compared to normal table columns? The main reason I want to use Redshift is the columnar nature of it because I want to perform complex aggregations on analytical data that I stored in Redshift.

It seems Redshift doesn't store data in columnar format for JSON data types according to JSON functions page in Redshift documentation. ([link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html)) However I know that some of the Redshift based analytics services stores data in JSON format. Does anybody benchmarked JSON format in Redshift? Is it really worth using even thought it loses the main benefit of Redshift?

Comment: The performance on a JSON column will not be as good as on a column that has a SORT key on. There is also some overhead for the JSON parsing, but if your data is not huge it can still be good.

Comment: @Guy, It seems Redshift JSON support is similar to Postgresql's JSON support. Since JSON data is stored as text, the data should take much more space and compressing would not be much effective. Also it parses the text and extract needed fields when querying which is same as what Postgresql does so it doesn't make sense to use JSON data type unless the data is too sparse.

Comment: You are right, but it is a matter to simplicity. If you don't have that much data and you don't want to extract the values from your JSON, you can use these functions. It will work and will work nicely. But if you have a lot of data, it is certainly worth it to extract these fields and use Redshift advance features like SORT and ANALYZE to get better performance.

Comment: I'm not sure how redshift handles json under the hood, but you *can* actually add indexes to postgresql json columns (same with mysql, even though no one was asking haha)  Check out the docs on jsonb indexing, here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a data point:

cluster: 24xdc1.large
table: 2.4B rows

```
select count(*) from table where json_extract_path_text(what_extra_json, 'is_logged_in') is not null
   count
------------
 1364239102
```

24.7sec

```
select count(*) from table where plan is not null
   count
------------
 1370337529
```

6.1sec